# Difference between android runOnUiThread and simple code in java

Tags: android, multithreading, android-runonuithread

I am a beginner in android application development.I am working with threads in android.I have read about a `runOnUiThread` which run code on main UI(if i am not wrong?i guess.).

My question is what is the difference between normal code on main UI and code inside `runOnIUThread`.

**Example:1**

```
class A
{
getDataFromServer(foo);//Code on mainUI
}
```

**Example:2**

```
getActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run(){
getDataFromServer(foo);
}
});
```

What is difference in both example.Please help me.Your response will be a new learning for me.

Comment: If you want to update UI in non UI thread then `runOnUiTread()` is used.

Comment: if you dont want use runOnUiThread () then use AsyncTask , it have preExecute and postExecute to interact with UI.

Comment: What if, i will update the UI form runOnUiThread can code inside thread goes to long process,will it block further execution(ANR)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that you meant simple code for UIThread code,

**What is a thread ?**

A thread defines a process running

First **runOnUiThread** ..

> Runs the specified action on the **UI thread**. *If the current thread is
>   the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately*. If the current
>   thread is **not** the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue
>   of the UI thread.

What is **UIThread**

- Main thread of execution for your application
- Most of your application code will run here `onCreate`, `onPause`, `onDestroy`, `onClick`, etc.

  So simply *Anything that causes the UI to be updated or changed HAS to happen on the UI thread*

When you **explicitly** spawn a new thread to do work in the **background**, this code is not run on the UIThread.Now what if you want to do something that changes the UI? 
Then you are welcome to `runOnUiThread`

You have to use `runOnUiThread()` when you want to update your UI from a Non-UI Thread. For eg- If you want to update your UI from a background Thread. You can also use `Handler` for the same thing.

Comment: Can runOnUiThread blocks further exection, in other words can it create ANR if thread goes to long process?

Comment: Well that depends. with your task..if there are any kind of a process you're supposed to use a Handler https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads t provides these background threads the ability to execute code that can modify the UI. They do this by putting the UI-modifying code in a Runnable object and passing it to the runOnUiThread method.

Comment: Activity.runOnUiThread() is a special case of more generic Handlers. With Handler you can create your own event query within your own thread. Using Handlers instantiated with default constructor doesn't mean "code will run on UI thread" in general. By default, handlers binded to Thread from which they was instantiated from. So if you suspect that kind of an ANR use a handler

Answer (score 2):

Normally your code is executed on your UI thread. For longer taking tasks (such as network requests, etc...) you will use a background tasks (Handler, AsyncTask, Thread, ...).

As your Views can only be *touched* from a UI thread, you use `runOnUiThread()` if you are executing code in a background thread and you need to update your views, from this background thread.

Comment: That means runOnUiThread run code in background? Can it create ANR?

Comment: No, you call `runOnUiThread` **from** your backround thread to execute code on you main thread

Comment: What if, i will use this....new Thread(new Runnable() {
            (At)Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    (At)Override
                    public void run() {
                        //Code here
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();

Answer (score 1):

To explain 'why' Android has the 'runOnUiThread()' option, it is important to understand that java is only used to create the bytecode (dex) that Android uses. The code running on the phone is NOT java.

Additionally, Android threads 'can' have a thing called a 'looper'. This 'looper' is what handles 'tasks(technically runnables and messages)' in order via a queue. The 'main ui thread' has by default a looper already attached to it.

That means that your runnable you created was put onto the looper's queue of the main UI thread. (this is why the runnable is NOT instantaneously ran, but will be ran 'quickly'/'soon')

The reason you'd use a runnable to run code on the UI thread is because you are in some other 'background thread' that you created... and want to update the UI in some way. (Only the UI thread can interact with the UI)