# Error: While inserting data in MySql from Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

Inserting 6 columns from android to PHP MySql showing these 3 errors
Implementing App/code using Fragment and this code is done on One of the fragment file.
Added Internet permission also in Manifest

Log Cat

```
06-23 00:52:53.830: E/Fail 1(1512):android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-23 00:52:53.830: E/Fail 2(1512):java.lang.NullPointerException:lock==null
06-23 00:52:53.830: E/Fail 3(1512):java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Android Code

```
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        addque = question.getText().toString();
        addc1 = choice1.getText().toString();
        addc2 = choice2.getText().toString();
        addc3 = choice3.getText().toString();
        addanswer = answer.getText().toString();
        addexplan = Explanation.getText().toString();
        insert();
        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Question posted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Insert Function in the same file

```
    public void insert() {
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addque", addque));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addc1", addc1));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addc2", addc2));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addc3", addc3));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addanswer", addanswer));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addexplan", addexplan));

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new
                HttpPost("http://localhost/insert/insert.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP 
        Address ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
    }

    try {
        JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
        code = (json_data.getInt("code"));

        if (code == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Inserted Successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
    }
}
```

New to Inserting in Data in Mysql from Android 
Thankyou

Comment: move your insert() in background thread, instead of calling it in main thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not allow any network operation on UI thread, you need to create separate thread to do so. You can use asynctask for this, like as follows:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        insert();
    }
}
```

Comment: after implementing this ..I am having one problem which is now it's giving error -> java.lang.RuntimeException:  **Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()**

Answer (score 0):

> You can't call network operation on main thread , you have to create
>   background thread which execute your operation.

**Refer**

**1.**    [AsyncTask Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

**2.**    [AsyncTask Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9671602/8164071)

Answer (score 0):

Your stacktrace clearly states that you are calling network API from the UI thread. You should use a background thread or [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

As for the [NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html) you need to move the insert call on a background thread which is due to

> You can't call network operation on main thread , you have to create background thread which execute your operation.

, for that you need to use a [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            insert(); // call insert method in this block
                      // which is background thread, 
                      // prevents network call to run on MainThread                       
        }
    });
```

and also if theres any update needed to run on the main thread on insert method call, [runOnUiThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632607/difference-between-android-runonuithread-and-simple-code-in-java) like Toast, alerts. etc

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Toast, Alerts or any operation that needs
            // to interact on UI, call here
        }
    });
```

if you are using a fragment call

```
 getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Toast, Alerts or any operation that needs
            // to interact on UI, call here
        }
    });
```

> PS: You need to have a clear understanding of these topics before implementing, So you have to go through the developer docs.